# Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, azure, javax.imageio

I'm trying to deploy a Spring web app to a Tomcat 7 running on a production environment on Windows Azure (tried Ubuntu and Windows Datacenter VM).
Sadly, I get an error while generating thumbnails in use with `ImageIo` (stack trace below).

During development, I used Tomcat 7 too, so I really don't understand, what is different on the production web server.

When I try to load the modules by `ImageIO.scanForPlugins();` the exakt same thing happens. Isn't `ImageIO` (or `javax.awt` in general) included in the standard Java 7 JRE?

#### Ideas that did not work

I've read something about setting up a subfolder in `META-INF/services/javax.io`... or running the JVM in heap mode but nothing fixed the issue below.

#### All fine on DEV machine

I think I really walk against a wall right now, because I have no clue how to fix this problem. On local development environment (Windows 8, Java 7 64 bit, Tomcat 7) I did nothing of this hints above (heap mode or class files) and everything worked perfectly. Has this something to do, that the app is running on a server without GPU or something like this?

Thanks for every reply in advance =)

## Log 1

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIOException report

Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
    ch.yooapps.resman.service.data.FileServiceImpl.createFile(FileServiceImpl.java:63)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.createFile(Unknown Source)
    ch.yooapps.resman.application.controllers.rest.FileController.attacheFile(FileController.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

## Log 2

Stacktrace from Tomcatlog:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/rp] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:155)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:65)
        at ch.yooapps.resman.service.data.FileServiceImpl.createFile(FileServiceImpl.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.createFile(Unknown Source)
        at ch.yooapps.resman.application.controllers.rest.FileController.attacheFile(FileController.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party ImageIO plugins deployed? I think ill-behaved plugins could cause ImageIO to crash during initialization and cause the problem you see. And to answer one of your questions, yes, any Java 7 JRE must contain java.awt.*  and javax.imageio.* packages.

Comment: I do use com.sun.pdfview.* for creating thumbs of pdfs but even if I try to get a bufferedImage without this lib I still retrieve the same exception. Is it likely that this lib crashes ImageIO on server but not on local environment?

Comment: Well.. *Something* is behaving differently. That's as about as much you have revealed so far. Assume nothing. Investigate everything. ;-) PS: I think you should find an exception in your Tomcat log that precedes the NoClassDefFoundError, probably an ExceptionInInitializerError, that will reveal the real problem.

Comment: hm i agree with you =) attached a new stacktrace from tomcatlog. as you said before, there is a ExceptionInInitialzeError.

Comment: Hmmm.. It seems that [`AppContext` is `null`](https://www.google.com/search?q=appcontext+is+null). Are you running the exact same version/revision of the JRE on client/server? Something happened around u25 that causes this. Not sure if it's fixed again, or if you need to apply some of the workarounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I fixed this issue =)

1. I **removed OpenJDK** from Linux distribution and **installed Oracle Java 7 > u25** by hand. (Good tutorial: http://de.wikihow.com/Installation-von-Oracle-Java-unter-Ubuntu-Linux)
2. Then I **added** an `ApplicationListener` which loads the `sunToolkit` by hand (because `AppContext` is always `null` for some reason)

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
   public class ContextConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
       @Override
       public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {
           //refresh awt context
           if(AppContext.getAppContext() == null) {
               SunToolkit.createNewAppContext();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks at haraldK =)

Comment: This has been broken from u25 (as mentioned previously by @haraldK) and from what I could glean from the numerous bug reports was expected to be fixed as of u60... however it is not fixed. Your code is a simple but effective work around. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Got fixed for me by adding following JVM option.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit"
```

Comment: This fixed it on my environment (OpenShift) as well. My JVM: `java version "1.7.0_121", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.8.1.el6_8-i386 u121-b00), OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.121-b00, mixed mode)`. For OpenShift, this would be useful: `rhc env set JAVA_OPTS_EXT="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit" -a yourapp`

Comment: "-Djava.awt.headless=true" alone did the trick for me. I did not need the "-Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit" option.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff same here the `-Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit` raise OpenJDK  Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/java/openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I have tomcat 8.5 and used it with `log4j` as a general logger. I changed the `tomcat-juli.jar` in the `$CATALINA_Home/bin` directory. and I got this error. I changed to the original `tomcat-juli.jar` ( a link `../../java/tomcat8-juli.jar`) and it worked again !

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04. What resolved it was to install and use **Oracle JDK 11 as the default instead of OpenJDK**.

Here is a good tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04

**Notes:**

- I did not need to completely uninstall OpenJDK or perform any other actions such as setting `JAVA_OPTS` or adding an `ApplicationListener`.
- What pointed me in the right direction: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/2242.