# Tomcat server generates `Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO` error after being moved into a docker container

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I'm trying to move a tomcat server that was run on a CentOS 7 operating system into a docker container. However, I got `Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO` error after moving it into the docker container.

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/lyenliang/ImageIOProblem) is an ant project that creates a `helloworld.war` file for reproducing my problem.

I've tried the following tomcat docker tags in [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat?tab=tags), but all of them create the ImageIO error.

- 8-jdk8
- 8.5.43-jdk13-openjdk-oracle
- 8.5.43-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-hotspot
- 7.0.94-jre8
- 7.0.96-jdk8-openjdk
- 8.5.43-jdk13-openjdk-oracle

The tomcat installed by `yum install tomcat` on my CentOS 7 doesn't have the ImageIO error.

Why does this happen?

The java and tomcat version on my CentOS 7 are

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

and

```
Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
```

Another fact that I found is setting `JAVA_OPTS` as `"-Djava.awt.headless=true"` instead of `"-Djava.awt.headless=true -server"` can avoid the problem.

Is it possible to run the tomcat service in a docker container with `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server"` and without `Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO` error?

The way I pass value to `JAVA_OPTS` is by setting

```
environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server"`
```

in the `docker-compose.yml` file

I've run `ps aux | grep java` to verify that the java program inside the docker container has `java.awt.headless` value set.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475739/could-not-initialize-class-javax-imageio-imageio) says you can set `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit"` to avoid `Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO` problem.

The full log is as the following:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mypackage.HelloworldServlet] in context with path [/helloworld] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
        at mypackage.HelloworldServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2516)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The `-server` option is the [default on 64-bit systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client/198651?noredirect=1#comment59707599_198651) anyway (you almost certainly don't need it).

Comment: When you set `java.awt.headless=true` you explicitly say that you do not want awt classes to be used. I think your problem is that you are passing JAVA_OPTS in a wrong way. And actually the value of `java.awt.headless` is resolved to `true -server` and not `true`. Please show where and how you are passing JAVA_OPTS to the container/image.

Comment: try passing the parameters in JAVA_OPTS in reversed order `JAVA_OPTS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true"`

Comment: `JAVA_OPTS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true"` doesn't work. I got the same error.

Comment: What is the full stack trace from the logs? That might help. As @michalk says, `-server` is not required. The `headless` option is often necessary. You are a bit far back in Tomcat versions; consider upgrading (though this has nothing to do with your error).

Comment: Hi, @ChristopherSchultz, I've added the full log to the end of my question.

Comment: No "caused by" after what you have posted? Usually "Could not initialize class *Foo*" has some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to move Tomcat server on Windows into docker container. `java.awt.headless=true` did not help. I could solve this problem by replacing the `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore` docker image with the official [AdoptOpenJDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk) docker image.